# Why doesn't != work for string index comparison?

Tags: python, string

I tried to run this code with input "AC039"

```
 code = input("Enter code: ").upper()
 if code[0] != ('N' or 'A' or 'C' ):
     print("The first character must be N, A or C")
else:
    print("Pass!")
```

It gave me the output error result:

```
The first character must be N, A or C
```

However, if I input "AC039" into the below code using 'not in',

```
code = input("Enter code: ").upper()
if code[0] not in ["N", "A", "C"]:
    print("The first character must be N, A or C")
else:
    print("Pass!")
```

The resulting output is:

```
print("Pass!")
```

Why doesn't "!=" work for the first set of code, since both code[0] and 'A' are string types?

I ran a check using type function on code[0] and it returned string type.

```
code = input("Enter code: ").upper()
print(type(code[0]))
print(type('A'))
```

returns:

```
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
```

Comment: `code[0]` and `'A'` may be the same type, but that doesn't mean the operation you're applying is the right operation.

Comment: if variable = ('N' or 'A' or 'C' ), then variable == "N". That's a property of the 'or' operator. Remember that some code in parenthesis is executed first.

Comment: @Kerighan why does ('N' or 'A' or 'C') take in only "N"? Could you advise as i think i have misunderstood a concept here somewhere

Comment: use `if code[0] not in ['N', 'A', 'C' ]:`

Comment: What did you expect `('N' or 'A' or 'C')` to evaluate to?

Comment: @KlausD. either 'N' or 'A' or 'C'. I'm not sure what went wrong.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

It's because the "or" operator compares sequentially.
from the given input "AC039",

```
code[0] != ('N' or 'A' or 'C' ):
```

what's happening from the above code is, comparing one by one.

```
(code[0] != 'N') -> True
(code[0] != 'A') -> False
(code[0] != 'C') -> True
```

since the first 'N' doesn't match with 'A', it stops going through other comparisons, 'A' and 'C'.

```
print('N' != ('N' or 'A' or 'C' )) -> False
print('A' != ('N' or 'A' or 'C' )) -> True
print('C' != ('N' or 'A' or 'C' )) -> True
```

However, `if code[0] not in ["N", "A", "C"]:` works because "not in" checks whole elements in the array.

I hope it helps.

Comment: _"what's happening from the above code is, comparing one by one."_: That isn't correct, imho. What's happening is that `('N' or 'A' or 'C')` evaluates to `'N'` since `'N'` is truthy, and the whole expression is reduced to `code[0] != 'N'`.

Comment: This answer is completely wrong.

Answer (score 2):

These two lines are identical.

```
if code[0] != ('N' or 'A' or 'C' ):
```

```
if code[0] != 'N':
```

Because the [operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_(mathematics)) 'or' checks if the first [operand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operand) is true, then it takes it; otherwise, it checks another one.

Examples:

```
>>> 1 or 2
1
>>> 0 or 3
3
>>> 0 or 2 or 3
2
>>> False or 2
2
>>> False or 0
0
```

As a result, you can apply this pattern to solve your problem.

```
if code[0] in ('N', 'A', 'C'):
```

or

```
if code[0] == 'N' or code[0] == 'A' or code[0] == 'C':
```

Comment: I tried the method if code[0] == 'N' or code[0] == 'A' or code[0] == 'C': and it gave me the same results. But if I use in it works

Answer (score 0):

I think this is best explained with a rough implementation of what `a or b or c or ...` does.

```py
import typing as t


T = t.TypeVar("T")


def Or(*args: T) -> T:
    arg: T
    for arg in args[:-1]:
        if bool(arg) is True:
            return arg
    return args[-1]
```

```py
>>> Or("N", "A", "T")  # equivalent to `"N" or "A" or "T"`
'N'
>>> Or("", None, 0)  # equivalent to `"" or None or 0`
0
```